# Rounding to the Current Time's Closest Half Hour?

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is if it's `5:46pm`, I would like to display the time `6:00pm` or if its `4:13pm` I want to display `4:30pm`.. How would I achieve something like this?

I tried this but it's not displaying the corrrect time and it doesnt have `am/pm`.. what would be the correct code to make sure that the correct time is displayed for the user viewing the website?

```
$hour = date('H');
$minute = '30'; //always 30
echo "$hour:$minute";
```

Comment: @Barmar Those 3 lines of code are copied from the link you provided :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$hour = date('H');

if(date('i') > 30) {
   $minute = '00';
   $hour = ($hour+1 == 24) ? 0 : $hour + 1;
} else {
   $minute = '30';
}

echo "$hour:$minute";
```

Comment: I get: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/site/public_html/index.php on line 32`

Comment: missing ";" at end of line $hour = ($hour+1 == 24) ? 0 : $hour + 1